# Looping through string in excel, replacing Chars with Alphabet

Tags: sql, string, excel, vba, loops

Im working with character strings in Excel, trying to replace the characters(ignoring spaces, dashes and periods) with the alphabet(in order).
These strings are in individual cells. I just want to do one cell at a time.
Ex. SG6 -099 will turn into ABC -DEF
and 3F5234-42- GA will turn into ABCDEF-GH- IJ

These strings will not be longer than 26 chars.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: `SG6 -099 will turn into ABC -EFG` why did the `D` get skipped?

Comment: fixed it, was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to combine two subs (one I had, the other I found).  How does this work?

```
Function replace_Text(ByVal cel as Range) as String


Dim editText$
editText = cel.Value

Dim i&, k&
k = 1
For i = 1 To Len(editText)
    If IsLetter(Mid(editText, i, 1)) Then
        editText = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(editText, Mid(editText, i, 1), Chr$(64 + k), 1)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

replace_Text = editText
End Function

Function IsLetter(strValue As String) As Boolean
' https://techniclee.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/isletter-function-for-vba/
    Dim intPos As Integer
    For intPos = 1 To Len(strValue)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strValue, intPos, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                IsLetter = True
            Case Else
                IsLetter = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

In a cell, type `=text_Replace(A1)` where `A1` is a cell with a string.

Comment: Im new to excel scrips, could you explain how this works? I pasted it in the view code for the worksheet, and I typed the string in cell A1, but nothing seems to happen. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Luke - Hurray! If this works, mind marking as the answer? (Check the mark left of the post)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using. It fills the output to the adjacent cell

Ex. 080110-  0015 would be the input
    ABCDEF-  GHIJ would be the output

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1:A6"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Call replace_Text("A", "1")

End If
End Sub
```

Above is how I would call the function.

```
    Sub replace_Text(C As String, R As String)


Set cel = Range(C & R)

Dim editText$
editText = cel.Value

Dim i&, k&
k = 1
For i = 1 To Len(editText)
    If IsLetter(Mid(editText, i, 1)) Then
        Select Case (InStr(editText, Chr$(64 + k)) > 0)
        Case True
        editText = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(editText, Mid(editText, i, 1), Chr$(64 + k), 1)
        k = k + 1
        Case False
        editText = WorksheetFunction.Replace(editText, i, 1, Chr$(64 + k))
        k = k + 1
       End Select

       ElseIf IsNum(Mid(editText, i, 1)) Then
       editText = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(editText, Mid(editText, i, 1), Chr$(64 + k), 1)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

Dim cel2

Set cel2 = Range("B" & R)
cel2.Value = editText


End Sub

Function IsNum(strValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim intPos As Integer
    For intPos = 1 To Len(strValue)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strValue, intPos, 1))
            Case 47 To 57, 47 To 57
                IsNum = True
            Case Else
                IsNum = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function

Function IsLetter(strValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim intPos As Integer
    For intPos = 1 To Len(strValue)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strValue, intPos, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                IsLetter = True
            Case Else
                IsLetter = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```